# How to update Post Meta values through the comment system

Tags: post-meta, comment-meta

I'm working on allowing users to rate posts - through the comment meta. Storing and displaying individual ratings is working, however, I would like to be able to store the average rating in the post meta.

I have this thus far, seem to get stuck on passing values to the post meta.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'add_av_rating', 1 );
function add_av_rating($comment_ID)
{           
    $commentdata=get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A); 
    $parent_post=get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']);
    //get rating, get post meta & calc 
update_post_meta($parent_post, 'average_wr', $commentdata);
}
```

Even when I put a value such as 'thisText' instead of $commentdata it seems to fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$parent_post` is an object, `update_post_meta` requires the ID, so should be:

```
update_post_meta( $parent_post->ID, 'average_wr', $commentdata );
```